# How to explain the first colon in Python slice syntax list[::-1]

Tags: python, list

I recently read a code snippets about how to reverse a sequence

```
>> l = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
>> print l[::-1]
```

#### Output

```
>> [6,5,4,3,2,1]
```

How to explain the first colon in bracket?

Comment: FYI, that is not the best way to reverse a sequence. Just use `list(reversed(l))`.

Comment: why don't you get rid of it and see what happens?  In other words address the list with only one colon [:-1]

Comment: @Alex what? How is that "better"? Maybe it's more general, but if you have a list or string I don't see any advantages to your approach  (and it's longer, less idiomatic and probably slower)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The colons with no values given means resort to default values. The default values for the start index when the step is negative is `len(l)`, and the end index is `-len(l)-1`. So, the reverse slicing can be written as

```
l[len(l):-len(l)-1:-1]
```

which is of the form.

```
l[start:end:step]
```

Removing the default values, we can use it in a shorter notation as `l[::-1]`.

It might be useful to go through this question on [Python's Slice Notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation).

Comment: `l[0:len(l):-1]` is something cmpletely different from `l[::-1]`. The equivalent would be `l[len(l):-len(l)-1:-1]`.

Comment: @NiklasB. Thanks. I didn't think of that. Fixed that in the answer. :)

Comment: @SukritKalra I got it! The begin minus step to get the index.And first the `len(l)` is the last item in list until the the index equal to the `-len(l)-1` out range of the list.So we get the reverse list.

Answer (score 2):

```
some_list[start:end:step]
```

When you ommit any of the slicing operands they take on default values.
Default values for *start*, *end* and *step*:
*start* - the beginning of an indexated iterable which is always of an index 0 when step is positive,
*end* - the ending index of an indexated iterable which is always its length (following the same convention as range) when step is positive,
*step* - the default step is always one.

When you're using a minus sign on step omitting other operands you're basically saying "return a reversed list".

EDIT: Funny, but

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6][5:-7:-1]
```

returns the same result as

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6][::-1]
```

in Python3. Can anyone comment on to why?
That means that default values of *start* and *end* actually rest upon the step operand (more specifically its sign).

Comment: I think the idea is that `[start:end:step]` will visit the indices that would be visited by a loop like `for (idx = start; idx != end; idx += step)`. Negative indices `idx < 0` are interpreted as the "real" index `len(l) + idx`. `[5:-1:-1]` will not work because `-1` is interpreted as the index `len(l)-1`, so we need to use `-len(l)-1`, which is the "real" index -1 to force the iteration to include the index 0